# AVContentKeySession API equivalent on MacOS/Safari?

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, fairplay, avcontentkeysession

I am implementing a Fairplay Streaming player on Safari.It needs to prefetch a set of keys from KSM before the playback. All the examples I came across implement AvContentKeySession api but it is available only in Swift and Objective-C(for ios). What is equivalent of AVContentKeySession API on MacOS/Safari?
Is there a reference code available to implement such a functionality on MacOS/Safari?

Comment: According to the docs it is available on macOS as well: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcontentkeysession

Comment: @sathish-rao please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Availability

Here is the availability list per OS, from the documentation:

> iOS 10.3+
> macOS 10.12.4+
> Mac Catalyst 13.0+
> tvOS 10.2+
> watchOS 7.0+

That means it's available on macOS 10.12.4 and later.

## Safari

Apple has an official example project for this (the next title), under the project you can find the **FairPlay Streaming in Safari** directory which includes an example for Safari.

## Official Example

Check the Official Example [here](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/). And here is the URL for today's updated [example as a zip](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/FairPlay_Streaming_Server_SDK/FairPlay_Streaming_Server_SDK_4.4.zip). **Warning:** You need to have an Apple Developer membership to download this.

## Helpful Resources

The following resources available on the Apple Developer website contain helpful information that you may find useful.

- General information regarding HLS on supported Apple devices and platforms:

  - [FairPlay Streaming Overview](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/FairPlayStreamingOverview.pdf)
  - [HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/)
  - [AV Foundation - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/)
- For information regarding topics specific to FairPlay Streaming as well as the latest version of the FairPlay Streaming Server SDK, please see:

  - [FairPlay Streaming - Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/).
- Information regarding authoring HLS content for devices and platforms:

  - [HLS Authoring Specification for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/HLSAuthoringSpec/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016596-CH4-SW1)
  - [WWDC 2016 - Session 510: Validating HTTP Live Streams](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/510/)
  - [WWDC 2017 - Session 515: HLS Authoring Update](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/515/)
- Information regarding error handling on the server side and with AVFoundation on supported Apple devices and platforms:

  - [WWDC 2017 - Session 514: Error Handling Best Practices for HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/514/)
  - [Debugging FairPlay Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2454/_index.html)